# Square bracket after parentheses in php function

Tags: php

When function return an array and we just need for particular key value can we use it like this:-

```
$obj->functionName($para)["x"];
```

is this proper way of doing this or should use variable?

Comment: People do it different ways for there own reasons, some may do it your way because it's shorter, some use variables because it can be clearer.  It's just down to choice/style and opinion.

Comment: I wonder why the downvotes. This seems like a valid question to me. I seem to remember that at one point PHP (some version before PHP3 maybe) did not allow this kind of syntax. But it could be I was just trying to do it wrong back then, being a total noobie and all.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it works fine, you don't have to make variable and waste memory.

```
<?php

function getArray() {
    return [ 'name1', 'name2', 'name3'];
}

echo getArray()[1];

?>
```

Comment: I think memory gets "wasted" anyway to hold the temporary result.